# Question regarding p-series.

Tags: real-analysis

How do I show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}$ is divergent for $0<p<1$ without using the integral test?

I thought of showing that of showing $\lim_{p \to 0^-} \frac{1}{n^p} \ne 0$ and  $\lim_{p \to 1^+} \frac{1}{n^p} \ne 0$

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Use the Integral test?

Comment: Can't use that since we haven't covered integrals in my real analysis course yet.

Comment: $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^p} > \sum_n \frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0<p<1$, $\sum_n\frac{1}{n^p}>\sum_n\frac{1}{n}$. Hence, since $\sum_n\frac{1}{n}$ diverges by the [harmonic series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#Comparison_test), $\sum_n\frac{1}{n^p}$ diverges.